# I would like to use different theme for vscode language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two languages setup in my vscode, the first is pascal and the second is python. I want to set atlantic night theme  for the python and wolf night theme for the pascal. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Theme by language extension created by julien saulou. You can customise your theme there.